Retain image resolution in matplotlib sublots
I have a set of images that I would like to show in a grid.  I am using matplotlib for this, but am not super picky about the plotting library.  However, I am using matplotlib because it allows me to put labels and such.
I would like for the resulting figure to retain the resolution of the original images.  So, in the following example, the images are each 195x240.  I would like for the resulting figure to contain a grid of 195x240 images.  So, the resulting figure in the example should be 5*195 x 5*240, plus extra space in x and y for margins, labels, etc.
import cv2
import urllib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

req = urllib.request.urlopen('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/OpenCV_Logo_with_text.png/195px-OpenCV_Logo_with_text.png')
arr = np.asarray(bytearray(req.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
img = cv2.imdecode(arr, -1)

n_gain = 5
n_bias = 5
fig, ax = plt.subplots(n_gain, n_bias)
for a in range(n_gain):
    for b in range(n_bias):
        axis = ax[a,b]
        axis.imshow(np.clip((1+a*0.2)*img + b*20,0,255)/255.)
        axis.set_xticks([])
        axis.set_yticks([])
for a in range(n_gain):
    ax[a,0].set_ylabel(str(1+a*0.2))
for b, beta in enumerate(betas):
    ax[len(alphas)-1,b].set_xlabel(str(b*20))
fig.supylabel('gain (alpha)')
fig.supxlabel('bias (beta)')
fig.set_size_inches(10,10)
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=None, hspace=None)


You can use the axes_grid1 toolkit to manually layout the figure exactly to your requirements, in particular using fixed Axes sizes:
import cv2
import urllib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import Divider, Size

req = urllib.request.urlopen('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/OpenCV_Logo_with_text.png/195px-OpenCV_Logo_with_text.png')
arr = np.asarray(bytearray(req.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
img = cv2.imdecode(arr, -1)

n_gain = 5
n_bias = 5

dpi = 200                           # pixel / inch
h = Size.Fixed(img.shape[1] / dpi)  # inches
v = Size.Fixed(img.shape[0] / dpi)  # inches
hs = ws = Size.Fixed(0.2)           # inches
pad = 0.1                           # fig coords
rect = (pad, pad, 1-pad, 1-pad)

horiz = [h, hs] * (n_bias - 1) + [h]
vert = [v, ws] * (n_gain - 1) + [v]

fig = plt.figure(dpi=dpi)
div = Divider(fig, rect, horiz, vert, aspect=False)
fig.set_size_inches(
    np.array([h.fixed_size for h in horiz]).sum() / (1 - rect[0] - 1 + rect[2]),
    np.array([v.fixed_size for v in vert]).sum() / (1 - rect[1] - 1 + rect[3])
    )

for a in range(n_gain):
    for b in range(n_bias):
        ax = fig.add_axes(rect, axes_locator=div.new_locator(nx=2*b, ny=2*a))
        ax.imshow(np.clip((1+a*0.2)*img + b*20,0,255)/255.)
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])
        if b == 0:
            ax.set_ylabel(str(1+a*0.2))
        if a == 0:
            ax.set_xlabel(str(b*20))
fig.supylabel('gain (alpha)')
fig.supxlabel('bias (beta)')

plt.show()

Please note that the figure might be bigger than your screen and, depending on the OS and backend, it might get shrunk to fit your screen dimensions. See this question if you need scrollbars on your screen figure.
